# Create linked list relationship between nodes having same relation to other nodes in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, linked-list, cypher

As in this figure

[image: Data model]

is it possible to create a linked-list relationship between all `(:B)` nodes that share a relationship `[:R]` with the same `(:A)` node, for all `(:A)` nodes in the database. If order is important, then assume there is a property `order` in all `(:B)` nodes.

Comment: Show how you tried to solve the problem. What did not work out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you have an `order` property in each `:B` node. I'm using this sample data:

```
CREATE (a1:A)-[:R]->(:B {order : 1}), (a1)-[:R]->(:B {order : 2}), (a1)-[:R]->(:B {order : 3})
CREATE (a2:A)-[:R]->(:B {order : 1}), (a2)-[:R]->(:B {order : 2}), (a2)-[:R]->(:B {order : 3})
```

Then you can use this Cypher query:

```
// match pairs of :B when b2.order is equal to b1.order plus one
MATCH (a:A)-[:R]->(b1:B), (a)-[:R]->(b2:B)
WHERE b2.order = b1.order + 1
// Create the relation between :B nodes
CREATE (b1)-[:NETX]->(b2)
```

The output will be:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

One additional option: use [APOC Procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/index32.html). The procedure `apoc.nodes.link()` takes in a collection of nodes and makes them into a linked list using the specified relationship type. An example of usage:

```
MATCH (A:A)-[:R]->(B:B)
WITH A, B 
ORDER BY B.order ASC
WITH A, collect(B) as bNodes
CALL apoc.nodes.link(bNodes, 'NEXT')
```

Comment: Is there is any advantage over @stdob-- approach in this scenario?

Comment: I believe the `apoc` version should be more performant, you may want to test both of them with larger test data sets. Also, run PROFILE on each of them and watch how the number of rows and db hits change, though keep in mind that procedure calls don't report db hits.

Answer (score 0):

```
MATCH (A:A)-[:R]->(B:B)
WITH A, 
     B 
ORDER BY B.order ASC // Comment out this line if the order is not important
WITH A, 
     collect(B) as bnodes // List of all nodes of the desired type
UNWIND RANGE(0, size(bnodes)-2) as i // Go through all the nodes except the last one
WITH bnodes[i] as B, 
     bnodes[i+1] as BN
CREATE (B)-[:NEXT]->(BN)
```